# React component state passed as prop is undefined in Jest test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am new to React and Jest, and now I'm trying to write tests for my Todo app, but I can't find a way to test components that require props/state for rendering.

App.js:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import AddItemBar from "./components/AddItemBar";
import TodoItemList from "./components/TodoItemList";
import "./App.css";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const App = () => {
  // Initial state for todos
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    { id: uuidv4(), name: "Learn React", complete: false },
    { id: uuidv4(), name: "Graduate from school", complete: false },
    { id: uuidv4(), name: "Get a cool web development job", complete: false },
    { id: uuidv4(), name: "Learn more new technologies", complete: false },
    { id: uuidv4(), name: "Enjoy working life", complete: false }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="container appbox">
      <TodoItemList todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} />
      <AddItemBar todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

TodoItemList.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";

const TodoItemList = ({ todos, setTodos }) => {
  var items = [];

  // Create todo item list
  todos.forEach(todo => {
    items.push(
      <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} />
    );
  });

  return items;
};

export default TodoItemList;
```

TodoItemList.test.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TodoItemList from "./TodoItemList";

test("should render without problems", () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  ReactDOM.render(<TodoItemList />, div);
});
```

I want to test the TodoItemList, but I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Which means that **todos** array is unreachable for the test.

---

What am I missing? How should I bring the todos state/props to this test?

As I have understood, the test does reach downwards to components below the one being tested, but not upwards the component tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TodoItemList` expects `todos` array property

But you're not passing it in `ReactDOM.render(<TodoItemList />, div);`

Just define its initial value

```
import React from "react";
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem";

const TodoItemList = ({ todos = [], setTodos }) => { // change here
  var items = [];

  // Create todo item list
  todos.forEach(todo => {
    items.push(
      <TodoItem key={todo.id} todo={todo} todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} />
    );
  });

  return items;
};

export default TodoItemList;
```

Comment: Yeah, this fixed it. Thanks... damn I'm stupid. never should do coding when tired....

Answer (score 0):

You’re rendering `<TodoItemList />` with no props. Your *App* component has a default state, but your test doesn’t render `<App />`, it renders TodoItemList directly.